# Scala extract from list based on condition

Tags: list, scala, dictionary, slice

I have a list of words as a list an I would like to extract words that are maybe of lengths between 5 and 10, I am using the following code but doesn't seem to work. Also i can use only val and not var.

```
val sentence = args(0)
val words = sentence.split(" ")
val fullsort = words.sortBy(w => w.length -> w)
val med = fullsort.map(x => if(x.length>3 && x.length<11) x)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
val sentence = args(0)
val words = sentence.split(" ")
val results = words.filter(word => word.length >= 5 && word.length <= 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
val sentence = args(0)
val words = sentence.split(" ")
val fullsort = words.sortBy(w => w.length -> w)

val med = fullsort collect {case x:String if (x.length >= 5 && x.length <= 10) => x}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to let a regex do more of the work for you:

```
val wordLimitRE  = "\\b\\w{5,10}\\b".r
val wordIterator = wordLimitRE.findAllMatchIn(sentence).map {_.toString}
```

This particular regex starts with a word boundary pattern ***\b*** then a range limited match for a number of word characters ***\w{lower, upper}*** then finally another word boundary pattern ***\b***

The method `findAllMatchIn` returns an `Iterator[Regex.Match]` for each match (matches don't overlap because of the word boundary patterns). The `map {_.toString}` returns an `Iterator[String]`